# Restrict Access of Synchronized Data Extesion

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have requirement to restrict access of Sync DE using custom Role Setting to some users , is it possible to restrict access of Synchronized DE in Email Studio and Contact Builder using Role and permission or with some other way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so there is a direct way to restrict access of synchronized Data Extension out-of-the box.If Salesforce Integration (Marketing Cloud Connector) is configured at a parent Business Unit, Child Business Unit does not have access to Sync DEs in Parent Business Unit.So one option is to only grant Child Business Unit access to some users, so they only have access to Data Extensions in Child Business Units or the Shared Data Extension Folders assigned to that Child Business Units. You can import the data of synchronized data extension to Shared data extension and then restrict access at child BU.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.